# Reversing the order of up and downsampling

Tags: downsampling, multirate, supersampling

When we are dealing with the problem of changing the sampling rate by a noninteger factor like L/M, we first need to the do the upsampling, and then the downsampling.

My question is that under which condition can we reverse this order?

Comment: Are you familiar with the reason behind the ordering of these operations?

Comment: I know about the reason why we use a low-pass filter, roughly speaking before the compressor and after the expander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with downsampling is that it can be lossy -- since you're reducing the sampling rate, you can introduce aliasing. So, you can reverse the order whenever downsampling does not result in aliasing.

For example, say your discrete-time signal $x[n]$ contains energy in frequencies up to $f_N/3$, where $f_N$ is the Nyquist frequency. Then, downsampling by a factor of 2 will not affect the signal: the "new" Nyquist frequency is $f_N/2$, so there is no aliasing.

See also [Which order to perform downsampling and filtering?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/36399/11256).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Aliasing reason explained, the most important point when the order can be interchanged is when the up sampling and downsampling factors are co-prime